# How to proportionally adjust column widths in a QTableView?

Tags: python, resize, multiple-columns, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to *proportionally* change the column width of all columns in a QTableView widget, so that each column has the same width regardless of the data. For example, if a table has three columns, each column should always have a width of one third of the available horizontal space - and the width should be automatically updated whenever the dialog is resized by the user.

So far I've only managed to resize columns to their contents, which is not what I want. Here's the code I've got so far:

**main.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>624</width>
    <height>329</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
       <property name="alternatingRowColors">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="selectionBehavior">
        <enum>QAbstractItemView::SelectRows</enum>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="btnPopulate">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Populate</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>btnPopulate</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QHeaderView

class GUI(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        uic.loadUi(os.path.join(dirname,'main.ui'), self)
        # button
        self.btnPopulate.clicked.connect(self.populate)
        # table model
        self.header = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
        self.QSModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.QSModel.setColumnCount(3)
        self.QSModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.header)
        # table view
        self.tableView.setModel(self.QSModel)
        self.tableView.setWordWrap(True)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)

    def populate(self):
        self.longtext = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ac tellus nunc. Phasellus imperdiet leo metus, et gravida lacus. Donec metus ligula, elementum at pellentesque pellentesque, suscipit ac nunc.'''
        row = self.QSModel.rowCount()
        for x in range(7):
            self.QSModel.insertRow(row)
            self.QSModel.setData(self.QSModel.index(row, 0), 'Lorem ipsum')
            self.QSModel.setData(self.QSModel.index(row, 1), self.longtext)
            self.QSModel.setData(self.QSModel.index(row, 2), 'Lorem ipsum')
        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = GUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've got the following questions:

1. How do I change the code to proportionally adjust the column widths?
2. Why doesn't `setWordWrap(True)` wrap the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved by [setting the section resize mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode). To get equal column widths:

```
self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

To wrap the contents vertically:

```
self.tableView.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

There is no need to call `resizeToContents`, `setWordWrap` or `setStretchLastSection`. Calling `setWordWrap(False)` will switch to eliding the text on the right, rather than wrapping.

Note that since the row/column resizing is done automatically, the sizes can no longer be changed by the user or programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Following example (PySide, using QT 4.8) will proportionally change the column widths to the width of the QTableView. When the user manually resizes the width of a column (double clicking or dragging the section header), from then on the width of that particular column will remain fixed while the other columns proportionally fill the remaining space.

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import QEvent

class CustomTableView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.section_resized)
        self.dynamically_resized = False
        self.fixed_section_widths = dict()

    @disconnect_section_resized
    def dynamic_column_resize(self):
        flexible_width = self.width() - 2 - sum(self.fixed_section_widths.values())
        column_count = self.model().columnCount()
        flexible_column_count = column_count - len(self.fixed_section_widths)
        column_width = flexible_width // flexible_column_count if flexible_column_count else 1
        last_flexible_column_width = column_width + flexible_width % column_width
        for column_index in range(column_count):
            if column_index not in self.fixed_section_widths:
                width = column_width if flexible_column_count > 1 else last_flexible_column_width
                flexible_column_count = flexible_column_count - 1
            else:
                width = self.fixed_section_widths[column_index]
            self.setColumnWidth(column_index, width)
        self.dynamically_resized = True

    def section_resized(self, column_index, old_size, new_size):
        if not self.dynamically_resized:
            return
        self.fixed_section_widths[column_index] = self.columnWidth(column_index)
        self.dynamic_column_resize()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize:
            self.dynamic_column_resize()
            return True
        return super(QTableView, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

The `section_resized` method which is meant to apply a fixed width for a certain column, should only run in case the `sectionResized` signal has been emitted by (manual) user interaction. The `dynamic_column_resize` method (which will be executed each time the `QTableWidget` changes width) shouldn't trigger the `section_resized` method because then there'll be an infinite loop, because at the end of `section_resized` the `dynamic_column_resize` method is called. Following decorator is used to prevent this:

```
def disconnect_section_resized(func):
    def wrapper(self):
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.disconnect(self.section_resized)
        func(self)
        self.horizontalHeader().sectionResized.connect(self.section_resized)
    return wrapper
```