# Set QTreeWidget equal column widths

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I'd like my `QTreeWidget` to have evenly subdivided column/header widths. I am aware of how to set fixed-pixel widths, but I'd like to be able to it fractionally. I know it's relatively simple to get the whole widget width and calculate the pixel widths, but my suspicion is that there's a more "correct" and elegant way to do this, using a SizePolicy or something like that. I'm using PyQt5, but I can easily adapt C++ solutions.

Simplified (working) code for reference:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

main = QMainWindow()

tree = QTreeWidget()
tree.setHeaderLabels(['Course', 'Date Created'])
tree.setColumnCount(2)

mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
mainLayout.addWidget(tree)

central = QWidget()
central.setLayout(mainLayout)
main.setCentralWidget(central)

# dummy data
for i in range(3):
    item = QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
    item.setText(0, 'Course {}'.format(i))
    item.setText(1, 'Date {}'.format(i))

main.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to proportionally adjust column widths in a QTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317828/how-to-proportionally-adjust-column-widths-in-a-qtableview) -> hint: just add `tree.header().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)` (obviously, before `app.exec_()` call, or, better, before the `if __name__` statement)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!